# Непонятные слова и моменты в стихотворении И. Бродского "Остановка в пустыне"

Tags: значение-слов, литература

Очень понравилось стихотворение Бродского, но в некоторых моментах не могу разобраться.

1. Почему оно называется "Остановка в пустыне"? Не могу понять, с чем это связано.
2. Особенные слова и моменты я выделил жирным шрифтом (значения слов я уже искал в интернете; ответа, который был бы доступен для понимания, там нет).

*Иосиф Бродский*
**[Остановка в пустыне (1966)](http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=7560)**

Теперь так мало греков в Ленинграде,
что мы сломали Греческую церковь,
дабы построить на свободном месте
концертный зал. В такой архитектуре
есть что-то безнадежное. А впрочем,
концертный зал на тыщу с лишним мест
не так уж безнадежен: это -- храм,
и храм искусства. Кто же виноват,
что мастерство вокальное дает
сбор больший, чем знамена веры?
Жаль только, что теперь издалека
мы будем видеть не нормальный купол,
а безобразно плоскую черту.
Но что до безобразия пропорций,
то человек зависит не от них,
а чаще от пропорций безобразья.

Прекрасно помню, как ее ломали.
Была весна, и я как раз тогда
ходил в одно татарское семейство,
неподалеку жившее. Смотрел
в окно и видел Греческую церковь.
Все началось с татарских разговоров;
а после в разговор вмешались звуки,
сливавшиеся с речью поначалу,
но вскоре -- заглушившие ее.
В церковный садик въехал экскаватор
с подвешенной к стреле чугунной гирей.
И стены стали тихо поддаваться.
Смешно не поддаваться, если ты
стена, а пред тобою -- разрушитель.

К тому же экскаватор мог считать
ее предметом неодушевленным
и, до известной степени, подобным
себе. А в неодушевленном мире
не принято давать друг другу сдачи.
Потом -- туда согнали самосвалы,
бульдозеры... И как-то в поздний час
сидел я на развалинах **абсиды**.
В провалах алтаря зияла ночь.
И я -- сквозь эти дыры в алтаре --
смотрел на убегавшие трамваи,
на вереницу тусклых фонарей.
**И то, чего вообще не встретишь в церкви,

теперь я видел через призму церкви.**

Когда-нибудь, когда не станет нас,
точнее -- после нас, на нашем месте
возникнет тоже что-нибудь такое,
чему любой, кто знал нас, ужаснется.
Но знавших нас не будет слишком много.
Вот так, по старой памяти, собаки
на прежнем месте задирают лапу.
Ограда снесена давным-давно,
но им, должно быть, грезится ограда.
Их грезы перечеркивают явь.
А может быть, земля хранит тот запах:
асфальту не осилить запах псины.
И что им этот безобразный дом!
Для них тут садик, говорят вам -- садик.
А то, что очевидно для людей,
собакам совершенно безразлично.
Вот это и зовут: "собачья верность".
И если довелось мне говорить
всерьез об эстафете поколений,
то верю только в эту эстафету.
Вернее, в тех, кто ощущает запах.

Так мало нынче в Ленинграде греков,
да и вообще -- вне Греции -- их мало.
По крайней мере, мало для того,
чтоб сохранить сооруженья веры.
А верить в то, что мы сооружаем,
от них никто не требует. Одно,
должно быть, дело нацию крестить,
а крест нести -- уже совсем другое.
У них одна обязанность была.
Они ее исполнить не сумели.
Непаханое поле заросло.
**"Ты, сеятель, храни свою соху,

а мы решим, когда нам колоситься".**
Они свою соху не сохранили.

Сегодня ночью я смотрю в окно
и думаю о том, куда зашли мы?
И от чего мы больше далеки:
от православья или **эллинизма**?
К чему близки мы? Что там, впереди?
Не ждет ли нас теперь другая эра?
И если так, то в чем наш общий долг?
И что должны мы принести ей в жертву?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тема стихотворения - размышление о родине, ответственности за свое прошлое. Он возвращается в Ленинград из ссылки в 1965 году и видит,что от Ленинграда-культурной столицы ничего не осталось. В этом стихотворении поэт впервые употребил по отношению к своим соотечественникам местоимение «мы»: «Теперь так мало греков в Ленинграде, что мы сломали греческую церковь, дабы построить на свободном месте концертный зал». "Греки" - не указание на национальность, а указание на принадлежность к культурным слоям, кому дорога античность с её гармонией. Это эвфемизм: греки здесь явно русские. Мотив ответственности за исторические деяния отечества проявляется у Бродского как сугубо личное чувство стыда, позора.
 Тема греков вне Греции стала для Бродского предметом рефлексии. В стих-и говорится о греческой культуре как основе культуры русской и об ответственности носителя культуры: «Так мало нынче в Ленинграде греков, / да и вообще — вне Греции — их мало. / По крайней мере мало для того, / чтоб сохранить сооруженья веры. / А верить в то, что мы сооружаем, / от них никто не требует. Одно, / должно быть, дело нацию крестить, / а крест нести — уже совсем другое. / У них одна обязанность была. / Они ее исполнить не сумели. / Непаханое поле заросло».

1. Абсида(апсида)- в архитектуре — крыша, закругленная часть помещения. В античных зданиях апсида чаще всего закруглённая пристройка , потом её стали использовать для алтаря.Лирический герой находится на развалинах греческой церкви, смотрит сквозь провалы купола и видит современную жизнь - символ разрушения всего того, что было символом красоты и гармонии. Материальное поглотило духовные ценности:"И то, чего вообще не встретишь в церкви,теперь я видел через призму церкви".(бездуховность, утилитарность)
2. "Ты, сеятель, храни свою соху,     а мы решим, когда нам колоситься". Поле возделывают сохой, культуру народа-образованием, знаниями о культурных ценностях.Чтобы народ был культурным, нужно хранить архитектуру старины как историческую память, источник культуры, тогда будут всходы (будем колоситься).
3. "от православья или эллинизма" - эллинизм - распространение греческого языка на негреческих,завоёванных территориях. Он имеет в виду цензуру, когда заставляют писать о том, что нужно государству, а не отдельному человеку, его душе.

Автор находится в позиции наблюдателя, Стихи о греческой церкви заканчиваются размышлением о потере ориентации в пространстве, времени, истории, культуре, этике: «Сегодня ночью я смотрю в окно / и думаю о том, куда зашли мы?» То есть не ушли ли от духовности (православия)и от своих русских корней, своего родного языка (эллинизма)

Comment: Чуточку добавлю. Под эллинизмом все-таки автор имеет в виду систему греческой философии и этики (?) Православие и эллинизм - серьезные конкуренты были в сфере миропонимания, и с *еллинскими безчинствами* жестоко на Руси боролись. По поводу названия стихотворения (*Остановка в пустыне*)... Последние строфы вполне разъясняют его смысл.

Comment: Согласна,возможен и этот смысл. Есть ещё одна мысль. В эпоху эллинизма здания и памятники стали  выполнять не столько свою первоначальную функцию, сколько становились символами богатства, господства и могущества эллинистических правителей и аристократов, а он рассуждает как раз о разрушении храма.Возможно, эллинизм здесь - отказ от духовных ценностей в пользу богатства и власти. А скорее всего - всё вместе. О языке я подумала в связи с тем, что ему же прямо говорили:"не смей писать на русском, пиши на родном (еврейском)".

Comment: Согласен с @ДерзкийGrantum . <<Эллинизм>> здесь употреблён как греческая мифология , философия , культура . В более тонком смысле - до-христианское миропонимание .

Answer (score 6):

> "Ты, сеятель, храни свою соху, а мы решим, когда нам колоситься".

Здесь отсылка к  "Притче о сеятеле и семенах".
Матф 13:1-23; Марк,4:1-20; Лук. 8:4-15

1. И опять начал учить при море; и собралось к Нему множество народа, так что Он вошел в лодку и сидел на море, а весь народ был на земле, у моря.
2. И учил их притчами много, и в учении Своем говорил им:
3. слушайте: вот, вышел сеятель сеять;
4. и, когда сеял, случилось, что иное упало при дороге, и налетели птицы и поклевали то.
5. Иное упало на каменистое место, где немного было земли, и скоро взошло, потому что земля была неглубока;
6. когда же взошло солнце, увяло и, как не имело корня, засохло.
7. Иное упало в терние, и терние выросло, и заглушило семя, и оно не дало плода.
8. И иное упало на добрую землю и дало плод, который взошел и вырос, и принесло иное тридцать, иное шестьдесят, и иное сто.
9. И сказал им: кто имеет уши слышать, да слышит!
10. Когда же остался без народа, окружающие Его, вместе с двенадцатью, спросили Его о притче.
11. И сказал им: вам дано знать тайны Царствия Божия, а тем внешним все бывает в притчах;
12. так что они своими глазами смотрят, и не видят; своими ушами слышат, и не разумеют, да не обратятся, и прощены будут им грехи.
13. И говорит им: не понимаете этой притчи? Как же вам уразуметь все притчи?
14. Сеятель слово сеет.
15. Посеянное при дороге означает тех, в которых сеется слово, но к которым, когда услышат, тотчас приходит сатана и похищает слово, посеянное в сердцах их.
16. Подобным образом и посеянное на каменистом месте означает тех, которые, когда услышат слово, тотчас с радостью принимают его,
17. но не имеют в себе корня и непостоянны; потом, когда настанет скорбь или гонение за слово, тотчас соблазняются.
18. Посеянное в тернии означает слышащих слово,
19. но в которых заботы века сего, обольщение богатством и другие пожелания, входя в них, заглушают слово, и оно бывает без плода.
20. А посеянное на доброй земле означает тех, которые слушают слово и принимают, и приносят плод, один в тридцать, другой в шестьдесят, иной во сто крат.
    (Марк 4:1-20)

Потом, когда ученики спросили Иисуса Христа: "что значит эта притча?" - Он им объяснил:

Семя есть слово Божие (Евангелие).

Сеятель - тот кто сеет (проповедует) слово Божие.

Земля - сердце человеческое.

Земля при дороге, куда упало семя, означает невнимательных и рассеянных людей, к сердцу которых слово Божие не имеет доступа. Диавол без труда похищает и уносит его от них, чтобы они не уверовали и не спаслись.

Каменистое место означает людей непостоянных и малодушных. Они охотно слушают слово Божие, но оно не утверждается в их душе, и они при первом искушении, скорби или гонении на слово Божие, отпадают от веры.

Терние означает людей, у которых житейские заботы, богатство и разные пороки заглушают в душе слово Божие.

Хорошая, плодородная земля означает людей с добрым сердцем. Они внимательны к слову Божию, сохраняют его в доброй душе своей и с терпением стараются исполнять все, чему оно учит. Плоды их это добрые дела, за которые они удостаиваются Царства Небесного.

[**Притча о сеятеле**](http://www.magister.msk.ru/library/bible/zb/zb146.htm)

Бродский пользуется евангелическим сюжетом, чтобы сказать о том, что греки, которым была уготована историческая миссия нести культуру, не смогли выполнить эту задачу:

~12. а упавшее при пути, это суть слушающие, к которым потом приходит диавол и уносит слово из сердца их, чтобы они не уверовали и не спаслись…
(Луки, 8:12)

Россия (Петербург) - это благодатная почва, где семена не взошли.

ЗЫ Подумал. Тут вообще-то может быть и несколько иная трактовка. Соха - это та самая сломанная греческая церковь в Ленинграде. Одно другого не исключает.
К сожалению, я не очень знаю историю Петербурга, но если не ошибаюсь, это было здание на Невском проспекте, неподалёку, кстати, от Армянской церкви. За такое обилие храмов разных конфессий Невский называли "проспектом Свободы Совести".
Ммм... Нашел. Это в начале Лиговки.
[**Греческая церковь на Греческой площади**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8)

Ну в общем-то тоже Невский.

Comment: Я тоже сразу подумала об этой притче, но не совсем согласна с последним предложением. Мне кажется, что тут надо еще обращать внимание на строку "Непаханое поле заросло." Получается, что терния-сорняки не дали семенам принести плоды.

Comment: Конкретнее, пожалуйста. Трактовок может быть много.
И последняя фраза у меня уже стала совсем не последней.

Comment: Я про "Россия (Петербург)- благодатная почва...". Видимо, мы с вами параллельно дописывали свои сообщения :)))) 

Я тоже про церковь прочитала. Интересно! 


Согласна, что трактовки разные могут быть. Каждый может прочитать/осмыслить по-своему.

Comment: >Я про "Россия (Петербург)- благодатная почва..."  
  
И все же, давайте уточним. Вам не нравится само утверждение или то, что Бродский имел в виду именно это? Второе недоказуемо, первое вполне очевидно в свете евангелического сюжета и на фоне разговоров о снесенной церкви. Разумеется, речь идёт об очень узком вопросе греческого просветительства. Кто сейчас знает греческий язык, ранее обязательный для гимназического образования (без которого не брали в университеты)?  
С Бродским вообще интересная штука получается. Его сейчас неоправданно усложняют и политизируют. Мне он таковым не казался.

Comment: Не согласна, что Россия - благодатная почва, думаю, что скорее тернистая.

Comment: Не, ну в рамках понимания Бродского и евангелической притчи она все-таки благодатная. )))

Comment: Тогда где же "колосья-плоды"?

Comment: Так то-то и оно, что они не взошли. По притче.

Answer (score 4):

> АБСИДЫ

Или апсиды - это  выступ здания, полукруглый, гранёный или прямоугольный в плане, перекрытый полукуполом (конхой) или сомкнутым полусводом. Очень часто в православных храмах именно в абсиде находится алтарная комната, самое священное место храма. На плане абсида выглядит так:

[image]

Вид снаружи:

[image]

> И то, чего вообще не встретишь в
> церкви,
>
> теперь я видел через призму
> церкви.

Лирический герой сквозь остатки разрушенной церкви ("призму церкви") смотрит на трамваи, тусклые фонари и прочее, то есть на то, что с церковью никак не ассоциируется.

> "Ты, сеятель, храни свою соху,
>
> а мы решим, когда нам колоситься"

Православие русские переняли от греков ("сеятелей") и лирический герой вменяет грекам в вину, что те не смогли в должной мере привить русским православие.

> эллинизма

Здесь, философия и этика, принятые у греков до принятия христианства. Если крайне упрощённо, то основные черты эллинистического мировоззрения - это культ человеческого тела, политеизм, власть граждан, свободолюбие.

Название скорей всего связано с пустыней духовной. Отсутствием каких бы то ни было ценностей ориентиров.

Comment: *Через призму церкви* - двойной смысл.

Comment: @grumant, естественно двойной, но при ответе на этот вопрос я старался не давать анализ стихотворения, а объяснить только интересующие автора вопросы, как можно меньше влияя на восприятие текста. Естественно, совсем без субъективизма в таком вопросе не обойтись, но попытаться-то можно.

Comment: Не думаю, что Бродский что-то вменяет в вину грекам. Какую же "соху" они не сохранили? Обращается  он к российским деятелям культуры("истеблишменту"), которые твердят, что "сеют разумное, доброе, вечное", а сами только разрушают.Как можно воспитать культуру, если её разрушают на каждом шагу и исходит это от  государства?

Comment: @Людмила, я лишь исхожу из того, что написано в тексте. Кого имел в виду автор под словом "греки" я не знаю, действительно, скорей всего не выходцев с Эллады, но вторгаться в диалог автор-читатель я тоже не хочу. Именно поэтому я и дал ответ, объясняющий лишь основной смысл, но не затрагивающий подтекст. Если автору вопроса интересно, он его со временем найдёт и сам, если нет - то произведение для него хуже от этого не станет.

Comment: Да, во второй части автор несколько раз повторяет : *от них... у них... они... они*. Понятно, кого он так безымянно местоименует.

Comment: >Какую же "соху" они не сохранили?    
  
Я ответил.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus! С большим интересом всякий раз читаю Ваши ответы и комментарии. Получаю огромное удовольствие. Восхищена вашими фундаментальными и в хорошем смысле академическими познаниями.